# gemset rails folder empty

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rvm

I am using ruby 1.9.3-p551 with rvm and try to install rails 3.2.17 with bundler. After bundle install and bundle show rails I see an empty rails folder. Is this normal? I am wondering why I can still start my rails server.
After starting the server I get 500 page error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found out how it works.
So the rails-folder is empty, but a lot of other dependencies are installed, like railties, actionpack, active record and so on.
And the bin/rails calls the railties which again calls active record and so on.